# Chrome with PHP, infinite loop

Tags: php, ajax, google-chrome, docker, websocket

I have a PHP app running inside a Docker container. While testing websockets I am using an infinite loop to wait for response from the server. Endpoint is an AJAX call triggered on click, ultimately hitting this method:

```
public function searchMessages()
{
    while (true) {
        sleep(2);

        $message = $this->client->getMessages();
        if($message){
            $this->_save(...);
        }
    }
}
```

From that point on, endpoint opens and never ends. I presumed that reloading the page would get me back to my home page (where I can click the button to trigger AJAX again), but that is not the case. If I try to close/reload, Chrome is just stuck on infinite load and never shows the page again unless I kill the container.

How can I keep on testing without shutting down my container over and over again?

Comment: Add a `break` inside the `if($message)`?

Comment: @Andrei how would I keep receiving messages after I receive the first one then?

Comment: use Server sent event instead of websockets, maybe it will help you.

Comment: Are you using sessions?  You could be running into a session locking issue.  Some web servers are also configured to only serve one request at a time per user.